# Error downloading protocol with https : // - Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I wonder how do I download files with protocol https: // in Delphi . I'm using idhttp , but when I click to download it returns an error code :

```
-1
```

After clicking the button, a few seconds it terminates the application.

```
uses: IdHTTP, IdSSLOpenSSL;

IdHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.create(nil);
 try
            IdHTTP1.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);  
            IdHTTP1.Request.Accept := 'text/html, */*';
            IdHTTP1.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0';
            IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
            IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects := True;
            IdHTTP1.get(FNomeArq,MS);
            Ms.Seek(0,soFromBeginning);
            header := IdHTTP1.Response.ContentType;
 except on E : EIdHTTPProtocolException do begin
             showmessage(intToStr(IdHTTP1.ResponseCode));
            end;
            on E: EIdSocketError do begin
                showmessage(intToStr(IdHTTP1.ResponseCode));
            end;
            on E: Exception do begin
              showmessage(intToStr(IdHTTP1.ResponseCode));
            end;
 end;
```

[image]

Comment: What exception class is raised? What is the error message. If you would just stop trying to handle the exception, you'd likely get some useful information.

Comment: What platform? Do you have the OpenSSL library files in the same directory as your executable?

Comment: This is what happens when you suppress errors. Please don't do that. You have gone out of your way to make life hard for yourself. You should learn to avoid handling exceptions.

Comment: If this is for iOS, See here: http://community.embarcadero.com/index.php/blogs/entry/openssl-and-https-support-for-ios-devices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, your error handling is wrong.  You are displaying only the `TIdHTTP.ResponseCode` property value and nothing else.  The only exception where the `ResponseCode` will have a meaningful value is `EIdHTTPProtocolException` (and even then, you should get the value from the `EIdHTTPProtocolException.ErrorCode` property).  The `ResponseCode` is not likely to be populated on any other exception, which is clearly the case in your situation. Since you are going to the trouble of catching different types of exceptions, you should display error messages that are meaningful to those particular types, eg:

```
except
  on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do begin
    ShowMessage('HTTP request failed'#13 + IntToStr(E.ErrorCode) + ' ' + E.Message);
  end;
  on E: EIdOpenSSLAPISSLError do
  begin
    ShowMessage('OpenSSL API failure'#13 + E.ClassName + #13'Result Code: ' + IntToStr(E.RetCode) + #13'Error Code: ' + IntToStr(E.ErrorCode));
  end;
  on E: EIdOpenSSLAPICryptoError do
  begin
    ShowMessage('OpenSSL crypto failure'#13 + E.ClassName + #13'Error Code: ' + IntToStr(E.ErrorCode));
  end;
  on E: EIdOpenSSLError do
  begin
    ShowMessage('Unknown OpenSSL error'#13 + E.ClassName + #13 + E.Message);
  end;
  on E: EIdSocketError do begin
    ShowMessage('Socket error'#13 + E.ClassName + #13'Error Code: ' + IntToStr(E.LastError) + ' ' + E.Message);
  end;
  on E: Exception do begin
    ShowMessage('Unexpected error'#13 + E.ClassName + #13 + E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Second, if you are running your app on a desktop system (Windows or OSX), you are leaking your `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` object, as you are not assigning an `Owner` to it, and `TIdHTTP` does not take ownership of it.  If you are running your app on a mobile system instead (iOS or Android), your code will crash, because there is no reference to keep the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` object alive after it is created.  The `TIdTCPConnection.IOHandler` and `TIdTCPConnection.Socket` properties use *weak* referencing on those platforms, so the object's reference count will not be incremented, and it will end up being destroyed prematurely.  If you don't assign an `Owner`, you need to free the object explicitly, such as in a `try/finally` like Zam's answer demonstrates.

Alternatively, if you are using an up-to-date version of Indy, you can take advantage of a new HTTPS feature that was added to `TIdHTTP` earlier this year so you don't have to create the `IOHandler` object explicitly:

[New HTTPS functionality for TIdHTTP](http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/blogs/changelog/20141222.EN.aspx)

Third, regarding the actual exception you are getting, `EIdOSSLCouldNotLoadSSLLibrary` means exactly what its name suggests.  The OpenSSL libraries could not be loaded.  This means either the DLLs (libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll) could not be found, or they do not export everything that Indy looks for.  You can call the `WhichFailedToLoad()` function in the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` unit to find out why OpenSSL could not be loaded:

```
except
  //...
  on E: EIdOSSLCouldNotLoadSSLLibrary do
  begin
    ShowMessage('Could not load OpenSSL library'#13'Failed to load: ' + WhichFailedToLoad);
  end;
  //...
end;
```

Make sure you have a compatible version of the OpenSSL DLLs installed, either in your application's folder, in a folder on the OS search path, or in a folder that you specify to Indy via its `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath()` function in the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` unit.  Typically, you should strive to always use the latest OpenSSL version that is available (which, at the time of this writing, is 1.0.2d).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are not using all required units.

```
uses
    IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdHTTP, IdIOHandler, IdIOHandlerSocket, IdIOHandlerStack, IdSSL, IdSSLOpenSSL;
```

This is working sample, tested under Delphi XE7 and XE8. FMX platform.

```
var
    FResponse: TMemoryStream;

procedure Load;
var
    LUrl: String;
    IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
    LUrl := 'https://google.lv/';

    IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    try
      IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
      try
        IdHTTP.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
        try
          IdHTTP.Get(LUrl, FResponse);
        except
          { We are hiding error }
        end;
      finally
        IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Free;
      end;
    finally
      IdHTTP.Free;
    end;
end;
```

do not forget to create FResponse by using `FResponse := TMemoryStream.Create;`

and last: make sure you are using correct OpenSSL library
for Indy 10.6.1.5182 i am using:

[WIN][x86] OpenSSL Shared Library 1.0.1.7; The OpenSSL Toolkit 1.0.1g;

```
libeay32.dll
1 281 024 bytes

ssleay32.dll
270 336 bytes
```

[WIN][x64] OpenSSL Shared Library 1.0.1.7; The OpenSSL Toolkit 1.0.1g;

```
libeay32.dll
1 817 088 bytes

ssleay32.dll
371 200 bytes
```